# What does 'rotating vector addition' mean in this context, and how does it generate AM and FM?

Tags: waves, information

I am currently learning about wave [modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation). In communication theory, it is said that 'rotating vector addition' generates [AM (amplitude modulation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) and [FM (frequency modulation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation). What does 'rotating vector addition' mean in this context, and how does it generate AM and FM?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with phase differences it is often convenient to to think of wave functions as the real component of vectors rotating around the origin in the complex number plane.  However, in the context of radio transmissions it is common practice to transmit “circularly polarized” waves. These have both horizontal and vertical electric fields 90 degrees out of phase, which can be received by linear antennas of either orientation. (The resultant E fields appear to rotate along the line of transmission.)   For an AM transmission, the amplitude of the high frequency E field oscillations is modulated at an audio frequency corresponding to the sound being transmitted.  For an FM transmission, the frequency of the oscillations is modulated. It is my understanding that FM is less troubled by static (such as that from distant lightning).